# ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(549)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS

Tags: android, webview, webrtc

Im trying to make an app that can video call using WebRTC. but the videocall WebView from webrtc didnt appear.

this is how i set up the webview

```
 fun setupWebView() {
    binding!!.webView.setWebChromeClient(object : WebChromeClient() {
        override fun onPermissionRequest(request: PermissionRequest) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                request.grant(request.resources)
            }
        }
    })

    binding!!.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
    binding!!.webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false)
    binding!!.webView.addJavascriptInterface(InterfaceJava(), "Android")
    loadVideoCall()
}
```

and this is how load the videocall from the webview

```
   fun loadVideoCall() {
    val filePath = "file:android_asset/call.html"
    binding!!.webView.loadUrl(filePath)
    binding!!.webView.setWebViewClient(object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            initializePeer()
        }
    })
}
```

and this is the error that i got from the log

```
[ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(549)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS

 I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es

[ERROR:address_tracker_linux.cc(245)] Could not send NETLINK request: Permission denied (13)
```